# Why cmake find_package get different version of Qt5 module

Tags: qt, cmake, clion

I use clion IDE build the project. Tring to using Qt5 lib. So I initialize the cmake script

```
find_package(Qt5  REQUIRED COMPONENTS  Core )
```

and got it runs ok. Seems I got the Qt5 lib. But I think I want to use the Qt lib at Qt creator.

So I followed the instruction at Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html prepare to compile my project. My system has two versions of Qt library. One is installed by Qt creator and the other one is installed by using apt-get from Ubuntu software center. I want to use the library 5.9.8 at **Path** =/home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64.

I have used **set(Qt5_ROOT)** and **set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)** set the variable. And use get_target_property get the module location of core, but I got a different location from what I want to use. The version of 5.9.8 is what I want to use.

```
-- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.9.8
```

So I checked the Cmake find_package at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html. What I found seems that **find_package** use the **config** mode and set the variable of **NO_DEFAULT_PATH** to ON. Then use the menu of **Reload Cmake Projet**. Still get the same result.

**Cmake script:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(qtcmake)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

set(Qt5_ROOT /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake)
set(Qt5_DIR /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64)

message(STATUS ${Qt5_CONFIG})
set(NO_DEFAULT_PATH ON)
find_package(Qt5 5.9.8 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Network)

message(STATUS "----------After-find-Package---------------")
get_target_property(QtCore_location Qt5::Core LOCATION)
get_target_property(QtNetwork_location Qt5::Network LOCATION)
get_target_property(QtWidgets_location Qt5::Widgets LOCATION)

message(STATUS ${QtCore_location})
message(STATUS ${QtNetwork_location})
message(STATUS ${QtWidgets_location})

message(STATUS "----------End-find-Package---------------")
message(STATUS ${Qt5_CONFIG})
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE})
message(STATUS ${PATH_SUFFIXES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(qtcmake main.cpp)
```

**Result:**

```
/home/ly/clion-2019.3.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/ly/CLionProjects/qtcmake
-- 
-- ----------After-find-Package---------------
-- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.5.1
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.9.8
-- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
-- ----------End-find-Package---------------
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
-- x86_64-linux-gnu
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ly/CLionProjects/qtcmake/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

**My slove way:**

I delete the **cmake-build-debug folder** and then reload cmake project the result got that:

```
/home/ly/clion-2019.3.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/ly/CLionProjects/qtcmake
-- 
-- ----------After-find-Package---------------
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.8
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.9.8
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9.8
-- ----------End-find-Package---------------
-- /home/ly/Qt/5.9.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
-- x86_64-linux-gnu
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ly/CLionProjects/qtcmake/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

So, seems the Clion menu **Reload Cmake Project** does work as I wish. But after I **delete** the folder **cmake-build-debug** at the project and then **reload** the project I get the result what I wish. So I thought that maybe the Clion problem or I didn't get the principle of that function at Clion. Maybe Who can help me with the rest of that?
Thanks...

Comment: Did you choose proper toolchain for your build enviroment (5.9.8/gcc_64) in Project Settings? This operation set some enviromental variables like Qt5_DIR, Qt5Core_DIR or Qt5Widgets_DIR, so you don't need to specify this variables manually in build script.

Comment: I think you point at the system variables one version of Qt, but I need to use another version of Qt library. I have already solved this problem, and I update that above. But I can't explain that. Thanks. @DaszuOne